# $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2\sqrt{\lvert x - q_k \rvert}}$ converges almost everywhere in $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\{q_k\}_{k=1}^\infty = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$. Then $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2\sqrt{\lvert x - q_k \rvert}}$ converges almost everywhere in $[0,1]$.

Let $A = \{ x \in [0,1] : f(x) = \infty \}$, then we want to show $\mu(A) = 0$. Also $f$ is not defined on $\{q_k\}$ but this is a countable set so contributes no measure.

We want to show that if $A$ is the subset of $[0,1]$ on which $f$ diverges, then the measure of $A$ is zero.

Comment: Hint: show that $\int f < \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. So if we let $f_k(x) = 1/(k^2\sqrt{\lvert x - q_k \rvert})$, then since $f_n > 0$ and integrable we can do $\int f = \sum_k \int f_k$, which is the primary move I suppose. Then the remaining sum is a convergent p-series.